# How can I get such a plot? Do not know the type of plot it is

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have data which looks like this:

```
file | timestamps
1 | 02/01/1970 
1 | 03/01/1970 
1 | 04/01/1970
1 | 05/01/1970 
2 | 06/01/1970
2 | 07/01/1970
3 | 08/01/1970
3 | 09/01/1970
3 | 10/01/1970
```

On the x-axis I would like to have the number of rows per `file`. On the y-axis I would like to have `timestamps`. It should look similar to this plot but I do not know how to get this plot. Is this a waterfall plot?

[image: unknown]

Comment: It's not a [waterfall plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot). You may be able to plot it with Matplotlib's `fill_between` function: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot of data, but this is the result with your example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, '02/01/1970'],
        [1, '03/01/1970'],
        [1, '04/01/1970'],
        [1, '05/01/1970'],
        [2, '06/01/1970'],
        [2, '07/01/1970'],
        [3, '08/01/1970'],
        [3, '09/01/1970'],
        [3, '10/01/1970']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['file', 'timestamps'])
df['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamps'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')

tot_delta_d = 0
tot_file = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in df['file'].unique():
  delta_d = df[df['file'] == f]['timestamps'].max() - df[df['file'] == f]['timestamps'].min()

  rect = patches.Rectangle((tot_delta_d, tot_file),
                           delta_d.days,
                           df[df['file'] == f].shape[0],
                           color='indigo')

  ax.add_patch(rect)

  tot_delta_d += delta_d.days
  tot_file += df[df['file'] == f].shape[0]
  
plt.xlim([0, tot_delta_d])
plt.ylim([0, tot_file])
ax.set_xlabel('Parquets')
ax.set_ylabel('Timestamps')
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

output :

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I assume it would look similar with uneven time gaps like seconds. So, I think I only need to replace `delta_d.days` to `delta_d.seconds`, correct?

Comment: yes, that should do the trick I guess

Comment: Thanky you very much!